# Add a missing property in a groovy @Canonical bean constructor call?

Tags: groovy, mop

I am new to groovy and just started exploring its metaprogramming capabilities. I got stuck with adding missing properties on a bean constructor call.

In a class to be used with FactoryBuilderSupport, I want to dynamically add those properties that are not yet defined and provided during the constructor call. Here is stripped-down version:

```
@Canonical
class MyClass {
    def startDate
    def additionalProperties = [:]

    def void propertyMissing(String name, value) {
        additionalProperties[name] = value
    }
}
```

However, If I construct the class with unknown properties, the proprty is not added but I get a `MissingPropertyException` instead:

```
def thing = new MyClass(startDate: DateTime.now(), duration: 1234)
```

The property duration does not exist, and I expected it to be handled via `propertyMissing`. As far as I understand groovy, calling the tuple-constructor results in a no-argument constructor call followed by calls to the groovy-generated setters. So why do I get a `MissingPropertyException`?

As I am new to groovy, I am probably missing some basic AST or MOP rules. I would highly appreciate your help.

Comment: as a workaround, you can use `Expando`, which ctor handles this: `@groovy.transform.InheritConstructors @groovy.transform.ToString @groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode class MyClass extends Expando { def startDate }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `@Canonical` and you define the first class object with `def` like you are doing with `startDate` the annotation generates the following constructors:

```
@Canonical
class MyClass {
    def startDate
    def additionalProperties = [:]

    def void propertyMissing(String name, value) {
            additionalProperties[name] = value
    }
}

// use reflection to see the constructors
MyClass.class.getConstructors()
```

Generated constructors:

```
public MyClass() 
public MyClass(java.lang.Object)
public MyClass(java.util.LinkedHashMap)
public MyClass(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object)
```

In the `@Canonical` [documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/transform/Canonical.html) you can see the follow limitation:

> Groovy's normal map-style naming conventions will not be available if the first property has type LinkedHashMap or if there is a single Map, AbstractMap or HashMap property

Due to `public MyClass(java.util.LinkedHashMap)` is generated you can't use `tuple-constructor` and you get `MissingPropertyException`.

Surprisingly if you define your `first` object (note that I say the `first`) with a `type` instead of using `def`, `@Canonical` annotation doesn't add the `public MyClass(java.util.LinkedHashMap)` and then your `tuple-constructor` call works, see the following code:

```
@Canonical
class MyClass {
    java.util.Date startDate
    def additionalProperties = [:]

    def void propertyMissing(String name, value) {
            additionalProperties[name] = value
    }
}
// get the constructors
MyClass.class.getConstructors()
// now your code works
def thing = new MyClass(startDate: new java.util.Date(), duration: 1234)
```

Now the created constructors are:

```
public MyClass()
public MyClass(java.util.Date)
public MyClass(java.util.Date,java.lang.Object)
```

So since there isn't the `public MyClass(java.util.LinkedHashMap)` the limitation doesn't apply and you `tuple-constructor` call works.

In addition I want to say that since this solution works I can't argue why... I read the `@Canonical` documentation again and again and I don't see the part where this behavior is described, so I don't know why works this way, also I make some tries and I'm a bit confusing, only when the `first` element is `def` the `public MyClass(java.util.LinkedHashMap)` is created i.e:

```
@Canonical
class MyClass {
    def a
    int c
}
// get the constructors
MyClass.class.getConstructors()
```

First object defined as `def`...

```
public MyClass()
public MyClass(java.lang.Object)
public MyClass(java.util.LinkedHashMap) // first def...
public MyClass(java.lang.Object,int)
```

Now if I change the order:

```
@Canonical
class MyClass {
    int c
    def a
}
// get the constructors
MyClass.class.getConstructors()
```

Now first is not `def` and `public MyClass(java.util.LinkedHashMap)` is not generated:

```
public MyClass() 
public MyClass(int)
public MyClass(int,java.lang.Object)
```

Hope this helps,